# Is there going to be a penalty waiver for IRA withdrawals in 2021?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, ira

If a person is having a hard time in 2021 and he is under 59.5 decides to take a withdrawal from his IRA, under current law he is subject to a 10% penalty. Now congress is debating another COVID relief package and it looks like it is going to pass.

Does that package include a waiver of the 10% penalty for early IRA withdrawals? I thought it did, but I cannot find a web site that supports that point of view.

Comment: Until it's actually passed, it can be changed and amended. It's impossible to answer this for sure at this point.

Comment: @glibdud I would be happy with an intelligent guess.

Comment: It isn't even clear if it is going to pass....